# google chrome full screen bug on mac

Tags: google-chrome

When developing a website, i like to go full screen. But i have noticed that when i do, hover states (a:hover etc) no longer work?

I spent hours updating css and deleting cache as i thought it might of been a caching issue, i even tried different code editors and editing the code live on the server.

Not sure if its just my version of chrome on mac (Version 51.0.2704.84 (64-bit) or has anyone else had problems with this?

Comment: I just saw the same behavior with OSX 10.12.3 and Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) OR 57.0.2987.110 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

There is an [open issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=170058) in chromium bug tracker for this. You can add you vote there.